# How to run my thread in parallel of while loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, c++11

Here is some code which increments several chronometers in parallel:

###### main.cpp

```
using namespace std;
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
 
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
 
#include "mychrono.hpp"

 
int main()
 
{
     
    std::vector<Chronometer*> car_crono;
    Chronometer chrono, output_chrono;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<std::future<Chronometer&>> futures;
 
    std::thread th;
    //future<Chronometer> ft;

    
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        car_crono.push_back(new Chronometer);
    }
    

 
 
    while (1) {
        
 
        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
            {
//
//                    //threads.push_back(std::thread(&Chronometer::start_chrono, car_crono[i], std::ref(chrono)));
//                    auto ft = std::async(std::launch::async, &Chronometer::start_chrono, car_crono[i], std::ref(chrono));
//
//                std::cout << "Hello-world" << std::endl;
                futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &Chronometer::start_chrono, car_crono[i], std::ref(chrono)));
                

            }
        
    
        std::cout << "hello-world" << std::endl;
        
        
        
        //auto ft = std::async(std::launch::async, &Chronometer::start_chrono, car_crono[0], std::ref(chrono));
        //std::cout << "Hello-world-2" << std::endl;
        
        for(auto&& f: futures){
                std::cout << f.get() << '\n';
        }
    }
    
    car_crono.clear();
    
}
```

###### mychrono.cpp

```
#include "mychrono.hpp"
 
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
 
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
 
 
//int Chronometer::hour(0), min(0), sec(0);
 
Chronometer::Chronometer() : hour(0), min(0), sec(0)
{
 
}
 
Chronometer& Chronometer::start_chrono(Chronometer& chrono)
{
  
  // if(chrono.hour == 0 && chrono.min == 0 && chrono.sec == 0)
  // {
    bool condition = true;
    while(condition) {
      sleep(1);
      chrono.sec++;
 
      if(chrono.sec > 59) {
        chrono.min++;
        chrono.sec = 0;
 
      }
 
      if(chrono.min > 59) {
        chrono.hour++;
        chrono.sec = 0;
        chrono.min = 0;
      }
//      if(chrono.sec == 10)
//      {
//        condition = false;
//      }
        
 
      std::cout << "chrono: " << chrono << std::endl;
 
   }
    
    return chrono;
 
  //}
 
  
}
 
 
Chronometer& Chronometer::finish_chrono(Chronometer& chrono)
{
    chrono.hour = 0;
    chrono.sec = 0;
    chrono.min = 0;
 
    return chrono;
}
 
 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& flux, Chronometer t)
{
    flux << t.hour << ":" << t.min << ":" << t.sec;
    return flux;
}
 
Chronometer& Chronometer::operator=(const Chronometer& other)
{
    // Guard self assignment
    //if (this == &other)
    return *this;
}
 
Chronometer::~Chronometer(){}
```

###### mychrono.hpp

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
 
#ifndef mychrono_hpp
#define mychrono_hpp
 
class Chronometer
{
    private:
        int hour, min, sec;
        //std::stringstream ss;
        //Chronometer chrono;
 
    public:
        
 
        Chronometer();
        Chronometer& start_chrono(Chronometer& chrono);
        Chronometer& finish_chrono(Chronometer& chrono);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& flux, Chronometer t);
        Chronometer& operator=(const Chronometer& other);
        ~Chronometer();
 
};
 
 
#endif
```

My program runs well my two chronometers in parallel each other but still dependant of my while loop. For example here I will print "hello-world" once but need to wait my threads stop to print a second "hello-world" message in my while loop.

My question is how to make my threads runs in parallel an be completely independant of others instructions in my while loop ?

Comment: as with the last time you asked this question just don't wait on the result of your futures and you wont block the main thread

Answer (score 1):

Tzig had a similar idea as mine, that is using condition variables and such.
I've made a full working example including comments and hopefully written for readability.

```
    #include <chrono>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <future>
    #include <condition_variable>

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // state of the timer.

    enum class State
    {
        idle,
        starting,
        running,
        stopping,
        stopped
    };

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // helper class for use of std::condition_variable, makes code more readable
    // takes into account the pitfalls of condition variables : 
    // https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables

    template<typename T>
    class StateVariable
    {
    public:
        StateVariable() = delete;
        StateVariable(const StateVariable&) = delete;
        StateVariable(StateVariable&&) = delete;
        StateVariable& operator=(const StateVariable&) = delete;

        explicit StateVariable(const T& value) :
            m_value{ value }
        {
        }

        void operator=(const T& value) noexcept
        {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_value_mutex);
                m_value = value;
            }
            m_value_changed.notify_all();
        }

        // atomic check and set
        T set_if(const T& from_value, const T& to_value) noexcept
        {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_value_mutex);
                if (m_value != from_value) return from_value;
                m_value = to_value;
            }
            m_value_changed.notify_all();
            return to_value;
        }

        const bool try_wait_for(const T& value, const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration& duration) const noexcept
        {
            auto pred = [this, value] { return (m_value == value); };
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_value_mutex);
            if (pred()) return true; 
            return m_value_changed.wait_for(lock, duration, pred);
        }

        void wait_for(const T& value) const
        {
            try_wait_for(value, std::chrono::steady_clock::duration::max());
        }

    private:
        // mutables so I could make the const promises on wait 
        // that they wont change the observable state (m_value)
        // of this class.
        mutable std::mutex m_value_mutex; 
        mutable std::condition_variable m_value_changed;
        std::atomic<T> m_value;
    };

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // helper class for storing elapsed time, helps with readability later on 

    class ElapsedTime
    {
    public:

        explicit ElapsedTime(const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration& duration) :
            m_duration{ duration }
        {
        }

        auto hours() const
        {
            return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(m_duration).count();
        }

        auto minutes() const
        {
            return (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(m_duration).count() % 60);
        }

        auto seconds() const
        {
            return (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(m_duration).count() % 60);
        }

    private:
        std::chrono::steady_clock::duration m_duration;
    };

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // formatter for ElapsedTime

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ElapsedTime& t)
    {
        os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t.hours() << ':';
        os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t.minutes() << ':';
        os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t.seconds();
        return os;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ChronoMeter class
    // note I use std::chrono classes

    class ChronoMeter final
    {
    public:
        ChronoMeter() :
            m_state{ State::idle },
            m_duration{ std::chrono::steady_clock::duration::min() }
        {
        };

        ChronoMeter(const ChronoMeter&) = delete;
        ChronoMeter(ChronoMeter&&) = delete;
        ChronoMeter& operator=(const ChronoMeter&) = delete;

        void Start()
        {
            m_start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        
            // exercise for the reader, also allow stopped Chronometers to be restarted.
            // for now just this simple state model
            if (m_state.set_if(State::idle, State::starting) != State::starting)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("only an idle ChronoMeter can be started");
            }

            // it is okay to capture "this" because the destructor of the 
            // chronometer synchronizes with termination of this thread through the future
            m_future = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]
            {
                // Set indication that the thread has really started.
                // this is important because when std::async returns, this thread exists
                // but may not have been scheduled yet.
                m_state = State::running;
            
                do
                {
                    // assigning a value to m_duration isn't atomic so protect it.
                    // we might be reading the value on another thread which might
                    // result in reading an intermediate state.
                    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_data_mtx };
                    m_duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - m_start_time;

                    // using a statevariable to check for stopping means it can respond 
                    // during the one second delay and stop immediately. 
                    // this is an advantage over using sleep
                } while (!m_state.try_wait_for(State::stopping, std::chrono::seconds(1)));

                m_state = State::stopped;
            });

            // Wait for the thread to have really started
            // this way we have a clear post condition for start
            m_state.wait_for(State::running);
        }

        void Stop()
        {
            // only allow a running Chronometer to be stopped.
            // in all other states Stop does nothing
            if (m_state.set_if(State::running, State::stopping) == State::stopping)
            {
                // synchronization with stopped state, as set by other thread
                m_state.wait_for(State::stopped);

                // future get is not really needed for synchronization.
                // but if thread threw an exception it's rethrown here 
                m_future.get();
            }
        }

        ~ChronoMeter()
        {
            // Automatically stop thread if this hasn't already happened.
            Stop();
        }

        const ElapsedTime Elapsed() const
        {
            std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_data_mtx };
            return ElapsedTime{ m_duration };
        }

    private:
        std::future<void> m_future;
        StateVariable<State> m_state;
        mutable std::mutex m_data_mtx;
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point m_start_time;
        std::chrono::steady_clock::duration m_duration;
    };


    int main()
    {
        ChronoMeter meter1;
        ChronoMeter meter2;
    
        meter1.Start();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

        auto elapsed_1_1 = meter1.Elapsed();
        std::cout << "Meter 1 elapsed time " << elapsed_1_1 << std::endl;


        meter2.Start();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));

        auto elapsed_1_2 = meter1.Elapsed();
        auto elapsed_2 = meter2.Elapsed();

        std::cout << "Meter 1 elapsed time " << elapsed_1_2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Meter 2 elapsed time " << elapsed_2 << std::endl;

        meter1.Stop();
        // not stopping meter2 (and it's thread) explicitly, this is done safely by destructor if needed

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this problem by making the multithreaded object handle everything that has to do with multithreading, here's how I solved it in your case (I ended up rewriting a lot of things so maybe the behavior isn't exactly the one you want, you can use my code as a starting point):

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "mychrono.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::vector<Chronometer*> car_crono;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        car_crono.push_back(new Chronometer);
    }

    while (1) {
//        std::cout << "hello-world" << std::endl;
        Chronometer::Time t = car_crono[0]->get_time();

        if(t.sec >= 10)
            car_crono[0]->reset_chrono();

        std::cout << "Seconds of T0: " << t.sec << std::endl;
        std::cout << "T1: " << car_crono[1]->to_string() << std::endl;
    }

    car_crono.clear();
}
```

mychrono.hpp:

```
#ifndef mychrono_hpp
#define mychrono_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
 
class Chronometer
{
    public:
        struct Time {
            int hour;
            int min;
            int sec;
        };

        Chronometer();
        void reset_chrono();
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& flux, Chronometer& t);
        Chronometer& operator=(const Chronometer& other);
        std::string to_string();
        Time get_time();
        ~Chronometer();

     private:
        Time currentTime;
        std::mutex timeMutex;
        std::condition_variable conditionVariable;
        std::unique_ptr<std::thread> thread;
        std::mutex CVMutex;
        std::atomic<bool> exitNow;

        void thread_function();
};
 
#endif
```

mychrono.cpp:

```
#include "mychrono.hpp"

Chronometer::Chronometer() : currentTime.hour(0), currentTime.min(0), currentTime.sec(0)
{
    thread.reset(new std::thread(&Chronometer::thread_function, this));
}

void Chronometer::reset_chrono()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(timeMutex);

    currentTime.hour = 0;
    currentTime.sec = 0;
    currentTime.min = 0;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& flux, Chronometer& t)
{
    flux << t.to_string();
    return flux;
}

Chronometer& Chronometer::operator=(const Chronometer& other)
{
    // Guard self assignment
    //if (this == &other)
    return *this;
}

std::string Chronometer::to_string()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(timeMutex);

    return std::to_string(currentTime.hour) + ":" + std::to_string(currentTime.min) + ":" + std::to_string(currentTime.sec);
}

Time Chronometer::get_time()
{
    return currentTime;
}
 
Chronometer::~Chronometer()
{
    exitNow = true;
    
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(CVMutex);

        lock.unlock();
        conditionVariable.notify_all();
    }

    thread->join();
}

void Chronometer::thread_function()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> waitLock(CVMutex);

    while(!exitNow)
    {
        sec++;
 
        if(currentTime.sec > 59) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(timeMutex);

            currentTime.min++;
            currentTime.sec = 0;
        }
 
        if(currentTime.min > 59) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(timeMutex);

            currentTime.hour++;
            currentTime.sec = 0;
            currentTime.min = 0;
        }

//        std::cout << "chrono: " << *this << std::endl; //Not thread safe be careful

        conditionVariable.wait_for(waitLock, std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

EDIT: About your latest comment: you don't need to reset a chrono in its destructor as the data will be destroyed anyway. If you want to reset the counter while it's running you want to call Chronometer::reset_chrono() from you main function.

For the second part of your comment, I added a get_time function to the code (I also added a mutex to avoid data races, I completly forgot when I wrote the original answer). When you want to get the current time of a chrono from the main function you just call get_time() and use the struct it returns to get the info you want.

I added a small example to show how to use both functions. As you can see, the main function doesn't even need to know what threads are !

I may be wrong but from the questions you ask I feel maybe you're not used to how multithreading works. It's a very difficult concept and one of the few I feel you can't learn only through experience, if that's the case you might want to learn about it from dedicated sites such as [this one](https://www.educative.io/blog/modern-multithreading-and-concurrency-in-cpp). I think I pieced together that you speak french, [here's a really good article (that was never finished apparently) about the theory of it](https://apais.developpez.com/tutoriels/c++/multithread/) and [another one in french, more about the specifics of C++](https://bousk.developpez.com/cours/multi-thread-mutex/). If you understand the core concepts and just have a hard time with my code, I plan on commenting it all but for now Pepijn Kramer did a great job explaining what they did in their response.

Comment: Thanks for your shared code, I tried it by using in for loop inside while loop with the following instruction  `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){car_crono[i]->thread_function(); }` and printed message "hello-world" but I'm not able to run the two chronometers in background. The message is printed once and then chronometer are running without being able to run following instructions. Do you have an idea for that ?

Comment: For example if I want to add `car_crono[0]->reset_chrono();` to reset the first chronometer in the following instruction I don't if it's possible as the thread still not running in background.

Comment: @ThibaultGrard you shouldn't call `thread_function` from main, I should have made it private, it's called by the thread created in the constructor, if you use my example without changing anything you'll see it launches two chronos and they both print their time every second

Comment: ok working well thanks, to reset a chrono should I use `void Chronometer::reset_chrono()` in the destructor of my class ? Also to get the result before destruction of chrono I guess I could use `std::async(std::launch::async, &Chronometer::thread_function, this);` instead of `thread.reset(new std::thread(&Chronometer::thread_function, this));` ? :)

Comment: @ThibaultGrard I edited my post to answer you comment, I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working perfectly as I was looking for ! :) Yes I'm going to check the link you sent to me to learn more about thread because they are useful but difficult at the beginning